# how to add internal style to the wysiwyg editor in react

Tags: html, reactjs, tinymce, wysiwyg

- I'm using tinymce editor in react app like above.
- I'm trying to show
  an editor to edit the HTML page which has many styles with flexbox in
  internal styling.
- But this editor does not support internal styling    and removes all
  styling forcing me to add it as inline styling
- I don't want inline styling when user submits the page

. By the way I'm using initialvalue to provide my HTML template.
But internal styling works on normal html/css/js mode example
[here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/basic-example/).

```
export default function App() {
   const editorRef = useRef(null);
   const log = () => {
     if (editorRef.current) {
       console.log(editorRef.current.getContent());
     }
   };
   return (
     <>
       <Editor
         onInit={(evt, editor) => editorRef.current = editor}
         initialValue={htmlTemplate}
         init={{
           height: 500,
           menubar: false,
           extended_valid_elements:
                'style[*],div[class|contenteditable|ref|data|style]',
           plugins: [
             'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
             'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
             'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
           ],
           toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | ' +
           'bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
           'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | ' +
           'removeformat | help',
           content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }'
         }}
       />
       <button onClick={log}>Log editor content</button>
     </>
   );
 }
```

Comment: This answer is related to your question. Maybe it might help you [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74250769/internal-styling-in-react-js/75837183#75837183)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to apply CSS to editor content, you can do so with the `content_css` option (for internal styles) or the `content_style` option (for external stylesheets) in your config:
[https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/add-css-options/#content_css](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/add-css-options/#content_css%C2%A0) 
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/add-css-options/#content_style

These options allow you to apply styling to editor content, but that styling is not then injected inline to the editor content. If you want it applied to the content when it is rendered later, you will need to load the same CSS/styling there too.