# Internal styling in react.js

Tags: reactjs

In react I have found either inline CSS styling OR separate CSS style sheets and CSS modules etc to import into the component . Is there no way in react of creating an internal  tag ie *internal styles* specific to the component, say on top of the component like we do in HTML

Comment: A React file is a JS file, so you can't insert native CSS in it. There are libraries for CSS-in-JS which have their pros and cons

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I discovered it few days ago.

```
<style>
  {`
      /*Your internal script*/
      /*eg*/
      body {
        background: #000;
      }

      button {
         color: red;
      }

      button:hover {
         opacity: .3;
      }     
  `}
</style>
```

If the stylesheet depends on user value;
E.g.

```
...
state = {
    userValue: "red"
}
render () {
  return (
     <>
        <style>
           {`
              .user-color {
                  background: ${this.state.userValue};
                  color: #f2f2f2;
              }

              .user-color:hover {
                  background: rgba(${this.state.userValue}, .3);
                  color: #66f;
              }

              .user-color:active {
                  background: ${this.state.userValue};
                  opacity: .3;
              }
           `}
        </style>

        <p>
           Your preferred color is : <span className="user-color">{this.state.userValue}</span>
        </p>
     </>
  )
}
...
```

I was looking for this internal stylesheet because i wanted to style my custom audio player (thumb and range) depending on the user value. So that's it.. hope it helps you or anyone facing the same problem.